# Xcode 4 - Dedicated configuration settings : build settings and schemes definition

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, build, settings

I'm totally lost with Xcode 4 build settings and schemes.

In Xcode 4, you have those items :

**A popup menu** in the main project window that allow you to choose the "target" you will run/test/analyse/...

[image]

**Some build settings :**

[image]

**The Scheme manager :**

[image]

**The scheme editor :**

[image]

Using those interfaces, How may I define many schemes that have their own build settings for the project.
I mean, today, whatever I do, when I change a build setting when on a scheme, let's say "Debug for me", and select another scheme let's say "Release", the build setting is the one I've changed.

For example, talking about the "RUN" action, how can I have different build settings for "Release on the AppStore", some others for "release on my iPhone", and other ones for "Debug on debug team's iPhone".

Let's say I want to change beetween those profiles the provisionning profile, add / remove some user-defined build settings, change the iOS target, and some other stuff like this ?

All those settings would apply to all targets.
Or specific targets if I want...

How does this can be done ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to make so many schemes. Even one is enough.

As you can see, there are "Build, Run, Test, Profile, Analyze, Archive" in scheme editor, these settings are for their actions in "Product" menu.

It means, when you clicked "Run" in "Product" menu, Xcode will use your "Run" settings in your scheme.

So, as your settings in your screenshot, when you directly "Run" your App, no matter on iOS Devices or on iOS Simulator, it's always debugging.

Also, when you choose the same scheme and clicked "Archive" in "Product" menu, Xcode will automatically use your "Archive" settings in the scheme, it would be: Release.

Finally, about the "DEBUG TEAM" thing, I am not sure what do your mean, but it looks like some special code sign provisioning file for your test team?

In this situation, you can either change your target's provisioning file setting before building or make a new target using the team provisioning file.

If debug is not required, just "Archive" your App and choose your team provisioning file to sign your App when sharing your App using "Organizer" would be very easy.

**Edited: Add some screenshot for help**
If you want have different settings for same Action "Run" as you said, you need different scheme as well.

Since Xcode allow you to add different Build Configurations, there is no need to create multiple targets. Just "Add" a new Build Configuration as "Pic1" shown, "TeamDebug" for example. Edit your target to set a new provisioning file for the build configuration or what ever you want to set.

[image: Pic1]

Then create a new scheme and edit your "Run" settings, choose the Build Configuration you've created before.

[image: Pic2]

And you are ready to go.

P.S. In Xcode 4, use "Archive" to build, find the App just builded in "Organizer", choose "Submit" to submit is a better way to release your App to App Store. Or you can also choose "Share" to share your App to the test team.

*Hope this Answer can help you out, If it dose, a vote up or choose it as the correct answer would be very appreciated.*

Comment: I knwow all of this. But just talk about ONE settign, let's say Run. How can I have some build setting for "Release on the AppStore", some others for "release on my iPhone", and other ones for "Debug on debug team's iPhone". let's say I want to change the provisionning profile, add / remove some user-defined build settings, change the iOS target, and some other stuff like this ?

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are looking for. Just edited my answer hope it can help you now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different build settings for different scenarios, what you want is different targets.

Create a target that defines the various settings for your build. After you create the target, you then create a scheme that uses that target.

Have a read of [Xcode Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html) as well.

Comment: one build setting = one target = one "makefile" ?

Comment: -1 does not require multiple targets! Can create multiple Configurations (in addition to Build and Debug) for the existing target(s).

Comment: As xuzhe and Richard mention, a build configuration is appropriate if you want to support different build settings for a single target. A configuration allows you to specify code signing identity, compiler flags, macros, and optimization level to use when building a target in that configuration. If, however you want to change more than that (ex: packaging info so you can build say a lite and pro version of your app using different Info.plist's), a new target is required.