# How to automatic distinguish two iOS app build packages

Tags: objective-c, app-store, testflight, compiler-flags

I am developing an iOS app and are using Testflight to send the app to my testers. In this app version I have a feedback form which the users is using to send me feedback. I want a good way to automatic distinguish some code in this build from the build I will send to AppStore.

Example:

```
#ifdef TestFlightPackage
//code for the feedback form
#endif
```

I can add a preprocessor macro for instance

```
TestFlightPackage=1
```

But I don´t want to change this everytime I create a package. I want a way to solve this automatic. Compare to publish profile in Visual Studio. If I choose Publish profile "Release" the flag is TestFlightPackage=0 (or the flag removed) and if I choose Publish profile "Testing" I will get TestFlightPackage=1

Which is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you need to create different schemes.You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299202/xcode-4-dedicated-configuration-settings-build-settings-and-schemes-definiti) a detailed answer on the similar question.